# Bitmap to Wallpaper resize scale setWallpaper

Tags: android, background, bitmap, scale, wallpaper

I want to scale Bitmap for Wallpaper set but no effect:| I have this code and all .jpg files in raw folder and array, code:

```
baton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        InputStream tapeta = getResources().openRawResource(textureArrayWin[n]);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(tapeta);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();

        int oldwidth= bitmap.getWidth();
        int oldheight= bitmap.getHeight();
        float skalaszerokosci = ((float) oldwidth) / width;
        float skalawysokosci = ((float)oldheight) / height;

        Matrix macierz = new Matrix();
        macierz.postScale(skalaszerokosci, skalawysokosci);

        Bitmap zmieniona = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 
                width, height, macierz, true); 


        try
        {

            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(zmieniona);


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

});
```

Comment: BTW. Wallpaper is too big, zoomed :|

Comment: Have you tried `createScaledBitmap()` instead?

Comment: Yes, tried... The same effect, It seems that setWallpaper is seting own resolution :|

Comment: Then I'd try WallpaperManager instead.  I'm not putting these in the answers because I've never set a wallpaper, so I don't know, but WallpaperManager may be better (setWallpaper is deprecated anyways). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29

Comment: Same effect, my image file resolution is 480x800 like galaxy s2, I want to scale bitmap dynamicaly to different devices.

Answer (score 1):

add to manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
    // Get display dimensions
    final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final int displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    final int displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    // Here I'm decoding a resource, just for the example sake
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture);

    // obtain the original Bitmap's dimensions
    final int originalWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int originalHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    // Obtain the horizontal and vertical scale factors
    final float horizontalScaleFactor = (float) originalWidth / (float) displayWidth;
    final float verticalScaleFactor = (float) originalHeight / (float) displayHeight;

    // Get the biggest scale factor to use in order to maintain original image's aspect ratio 
    final float scaleFactor = Math.max(verticalScaleFactor, horizontalScaleFactor);
    final int finalWidth = (int) (originalWidth / scaleFactor);
    final int finalHeight = (int) (originalHeight / scaleFactor);

     // Create the final bitmap
    final Bitmap wallpaperBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmap, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);

    // Recycle the original bitmap
    bitmap.recycle();

    // Finally set it as wallpaper
    try {
        final WallpaperManager wallMan = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        wallMan.setBitmap(wallpaperBmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Wallpaper", "Something went wrong: " + e.toString());
        wallpaperBmp.recycle();
    }
```

Also, don't forget to add the SET_WALLPAPER to your manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```